# Load a graph from a generated url

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to build an online html/css/javascript playground. When the code draws a graph, I want to be able to generate a url, with which users could load this graph in a browser.

At the moment, in the playground, I have a button that links to the function `generateUrl`:

```
$scope.generateUrl = function () {
    urls.create({
        // allCode is a string like "<html><body><canvas ...>...</canvas><script>...</script></html>"
        content: $scope.allCode
    }).success(function (url) {
        alert(url._id)
    });
};
```

Then, I want to load with the id of a url like `localhost:3000/urls/58a56d0962bd39979d142e27` in a browser:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('urls', {
            url: '/urls/{id}',
            template: "{{url.content}}",
            controller: 'UrlCtrl',
            resolve: {
                url: ['$stateParams', 'urls', function ($stateParams, urls) {
                    return urls.get($stateParams.id);
                }]
            }
        })
```

However, the above code just shows the string rather than the graph:

[image]

Additionally, it is embedded in `<ui-view></ui-view>` of my global `index.ejs`. The behaviour is expected, but it is not what I want users to see when they load `www.mysite.com/urls/58a56d0962bd39979d142e27`.

Does anyone know how to set up loading a graph from a generated url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to use Angular's [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service, more known as `$sce`.

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context. One example of such a context is binding arbitrary html controlled by the user via ng-bind-html. We refer to these contexts as privileged or SCE contexts.

So, you can either use the `ngBindHtml` directive, instead of plain interpolation.

```
<div ng-bind-html="url.content"></div>
```

Or, you could also inject `$sce` on your `url` resolve function and call `trustAsHtml` method:

```
resolve: {
    url: ['$sce', '$stateParams', 'urls', function ($sce, $stateParams, urls) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(urls.get($stateParams.id));
    }]
}
```

I'm not sure what's gonna happen if your HTML code contains the `html` and `body` tags. Maybe you'll need to remove those.

Comment: Actually, i realised that we need to use `ng-bind-html` and `$sce.trustAsHtml` at the same time...