# Make a web page with a folder of external files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angular-ui-router, angularjs-sce

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273331/702977), I used `$sce.trustAsHtml(aString)` to inject a string (eg, `<html>...</html>`) to a template `<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>` to display a graph when loading a generated URL:

```
.state('urls', {
    url: '/urls/{id}',
    template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
    controller: 'UrlCtrl',
    resolve: {
        url: ['$stateParams', 'urls', function ($stateParams, urls) {
            return urls.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
    }
})

app.controller('UrlCtrl', ['$sce', '$scope', 'url', function($sce, $scope, url) {
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(url.content);
}]);
```

Now, the html to generate a graph contains references to other files, eg, `<script src="script.js"></script>`. So I need **a folder of files** (`.html`, `.css`, `.js`) to draw a graph. I can put the whole folder in my server, but the problem is **how to inject these files to the template**.

I tried `templateUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/tmp/ZPBSytN5GpOwQN51AAAD/index.html'`, loading `localhost:3000/#/urls/58b8c55b5d18ed6163324fb4` in the browser does load the html page. However, `script.js` is NOT loaded, an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` is shown in the console log.

Does anyone know how to amend this?

Otherwise, is there any other ways to say something like `src=http://localhost:3000/tmp/ZPBSytN5GpOwQN51AAAD/index.html` (like in `iframe`)? Then, `<script src="script.js"></script>` in `index.html` will know it refers to the `script.js` in the same folder.

**Edit 1:** Following the comment of @Icycool , I changed to `templateUrl: '/htmls/test.html'`, and `test.html` contains `<div ng-include="'http://localhost:3000/tmp/ZPBSytN5GpOwQN51AAAD/index.html'"></div>`. The test showed it did load `test.html` and `index.html`, but NOT `script.js`: `GET http://localhost:3000/script.js?_=1488543470023 404 (Not Found)`.

**Edit 2:** I have created two files for test purpose: [index.html](https://www.matrixlead.com/tmp/index.html) and [script.js](https://www.matrixlead.com/tmp/script.js). **Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FwC85TGRNyTc5cQFeU8s?p=preview)**, neither `template` nor `templateUrl` works, as explained...

Comment: have you tried `ng-include`?

Comment: I just tried `ng-include`, it has the same problem, please see my update...

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include ?

Comment: You probably want to create a directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Could you create a plnkr to reproduce the problem? I read it multiple times but I don't know how to create a testing scenario.

Comment: please see my update: @lin

Comment: @SoftTimur the plnkr does not help because it does not reproduce your error. It load an template which is blocked by the following error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=https:%2F%2Fwww.matrixandcompany.com%2Ftest%2Findex.html
Please create a plnkr that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- one limitation is that I have to keep the code of `index.html` and `script.js` as they are; I could not add eg, `type="text/javascript-lazy"`. I can only modify the way to load them...

Comment: Please create a pluker. It is hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: I've finally made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FwC85TGRNyTc5cQFeU8s?p=preview).

Comment: @SoftTimur This could be a shot in dark because i've never come across the particular use case you are trying to solve. What if you included a base tag in the index.html page with the full url.

Comment: I really don't want to modify `index.html`... @MikeLunn

Comment: I believe you need something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing to make your script downloadable. But I haven't done that, I only have read of it

Comment: I cheated a little i guess, but this works: https://plnkr.co/edit/XE0sess3I2sl6vavq5Wr?p=preview and you dont have to modify the index file, its just code in the `run` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `<object>` if you prefer.

```
<object type="text/html" data="https://www.matrixlead.com/tmp/index.html"></object>
```

See updated plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DfavHNXXr5ztZC6qMgu4?p=preview).

Comment: Great one, this was simple. What are the limitations by using `object` in this case?

Comment: `object` element is supported by all common web browsers; but some of its attributes like `border`, `tabindex` are not supported in HTML5. See the reference document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object).

Answer (score 3):

You script that you are including is it just radom javascript or it is from other angular project?

I have done this before but can't remember exactly the step by step process, but hope this directs you in the right direction:

- White list the URL that you are including.
- Istead for ng-include have a look on how I did with function that return the path.
- Also in the routing you need to add lazyload to inject Views + controller

**Here is how I did:**
To load the external controller and the view I used ocLazyLoad.

https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad and had something like this defined:

```
 .state('Home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:3333/app/views/home.html',
                    resolve: {

                            loadPlugin: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load('http://localhost:3333/app/views/header.html');
                            }]
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

To load external view I had created a function in my app that basically takes the external base url and appends the view and than returns it, because when I loaded an external app it mixed up all my URL and I had 404.

**app.js**

```
 $rootScope.OtherAppUrl = 'http://localhost:3333/';

 $rootScope.appendOtherAppUrl  = function(relativeURL) {
            return $rootScope.OtherApp + relativeURL;
        }
```

**And in the view to include I had like this**

```
<footer relativeurl="App/views/footer.html"></footer>
```

**And don't forget to whitelist the URL's in your app.js**

```
angular.module('App').config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
      // Allow same origin resource loads.
      'self',

      // This code is CASE SENSITIVE
      'http://localhost:3333/app/views/header.html',
      'http://localhost:3333/app/views/footer.html',


    ]);

    // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
      'http://myapp.example.com**'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: @SoftTimur I have updated my answear, I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you... The scripts I want to preview are random, but I can modify them. They are not necessarily angular project.

Comment: hi @SoftTimur, I would have thought you would have marked this as the right answer as giving you several option on how to do it.

Comment: To be honest, I have not tested your answer, given `<object>` works for me so far. I notice one important thing from your answer: you can load external sources CROSS domain by a white list. I will keep in mind your solution and come back when I meet such a complex case... Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

I share also a solution by `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="https://www.matrixlead.com/tmp/index.html" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

and a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/r3FYX2uI2kCibp2ZwCni?p=preview).

The problem with `iframe` is that I'm afraid there are still (hidden) borders, and the frame may not occupy the full web page by default.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but might have gone a little too far. I created a `script` directive instead which will put the not-loaded `script` to the `head` of `document`. Something like this:

```
app.directive('script', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
      scriptNode.src = attr.src;
      scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.head.appendChild(scriptNode);
    }
  };
});
```

But, this obviously has few limitations including the `src` must be some absolute path. (Can overcome that but it would be dirtier..)

I have put the sample HTML file somewhere I can tweak a little and use it to come up with this [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XDzpE0h9R4aWIeUNA6BS?p=preview)