# Get the value of a variable out of <iframe> or <object>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, iframe, html-object

In my global html template, I have embedded an `iframe`, which can live-preview `{{src}}` (eg, `src` could be `public/tmp/bDCZ5rynnpLaYNEuAAAj/index.html`).

```
<iframe id="myiframe" ng-src="{{src}}"></iframe>
```

The `index.html` is a file written by my server; I have control of the code and I can modify it. `index.html` contains JavaScript code, it is designed such that it always has an internal variable `$output`.

My question is, how to get the value of `$output` out of the `iframe` and let the global html page know the value.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

**Edit 1:** I am also open to solutions where `index.html` could send the value to the server or create a file with the value, as long as the global template could get it later. Additionally, as I mention in comments, the purpose of `iframe` is to live-preview a folder of files, there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569214/make-a-web-page-with-a-folder-of-external-files) to do so (eg, using `<object>`), does anyone know which way could let me get an internal value out?

**Edit 2:** I have made a [plunker with iframe](https://plnkr.co/edit/5bByYqwrrzkslLK6Fnc2?p=preview) and a [plunker with object](https://plnkr.co/edit/uSik7MYblkTdTofu2v1B?p=preview). `$output` is defined by `<script>var $output="Default"</script>` in [indexOutput.html](https://www.matrixlead.com/tmp/indexOutput.html). My goal is to get this value out.

**Edit 3:** I just realised that `window.parent._resetter` that @Roy suggested in his answer works. But one thing is, the `_resetter` function must be defined in the script of the html page. Does anyone know how to **pass this value to my controller**? Here is [a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ak4mswbHeqKQZHl0zrUl?p=preview), and [a plunker with $window](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sp6uiPmLQIVQj3IWoJSa?p=preview).

Comment: At the moment, I choose `iframe` because it is simple. There are also other options of [live-previewing files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42569214/702977).

Comment: Nothing offense SoftTimur, iframes are simple till the moment you hit their limitations.

Comment: "same origin"? @plnkr not!

Comment: I just added a version with `ui-view`, is it "a partial view" that you referred to? is it "same origin" now?

Comment: Nope its not. I won't help here. My role is the commentary boy. =) Im fine while staying away from iframe questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can comunicate between root and iframe with `window.parent.someFunction` called from the iframe.
You have to create a function in root that recive a param and re setter to itself.

```
function _resetter(param){
  var paramRoot = param;
}
```

And call this function from the iframe passing the param `ouput`

```
window.parent._resetter(param);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161402/7349445

Comment: Note: This only works if the iframe is same origin to his parent.

Comment: Yep, @SoftTimur said "The index.html is a file written by my server;"

Comment: Yes, it is in the same server. I modified slightly the OP. I tried to define `$scope._resetter` in the controller. It does not seem to be called. Maybe `window.parent` does not refer well to the `$scope`?

Comment: @SoftTimur and now you hit a limitation =)

Comment: The limitation is about calling iFrame with a local file, or interaction of iFrame and angular?

Comment: Interacting with an JavaScript application in an uncommon way. This is where the problems begin. =)

Comment: If I don't use `iframe` to live-preview a folder of files, which way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42569214/702977) you think could let me get the internal value out?

Comment: Use a partial view of AngularJS and AngularJS goodness will be yours.

Comment: That approach falls over when the files are fully qualified HTML documents with links and scripts.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle showing the issue. It should be relatively easy to resolve your scoping issues.

Comment: @Yoda he need your help.

Comment: @Roy actually, `window.parent` works, please see my **Edit 3**.

Comment: I have finally found it. We need to add `$scope.$digest()` to update the view. Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ks10lCgrPesLxCgDyvmc?p=preview).